# Evaluating integral involving product of cosine inverse

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate the below mentioned integral which involves product of two cosine inverses and two variables $x$ and $y$. I need to evaluate the integral or get an approximate value of this expression and as I need to use it to calculate the probability of an event. Any help or pointers in getting the value of this integral?
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{4x}{\pi^2}\int_1^2 y \arccos\Big(\frac{y^2+3}{4y}\Big) \arccos\Big(\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{2xy}\Big)\,dy\,dx
$$

Comment: Maybe start by switching the order of integration and integrate by parts to get rid of the second arccos?

Comment: I have very rudimentary knowledge of the integration by parts. Can you elaborate a bit further ?

Comment: I'm truly not trying to be a jerk here ... but you should really master integration by parts in the single-integral setting before trying to do double integrals at all.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives $$0.0532405 + 0.0506987 \cdot i$$ as a numerical approximation.

Comment: You are right I should and perhaps I would be working on that and renewing some of the learned skills. Thanks for the advice :)